# Why separate AVDD and DVDD if the datasheet recommends powering them from the same supply?

Tags: power, digital-logic, analog

I am working on a bio-impedance analysis project and am using the [Analog AD5933 IC](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad5933.html), since it seems like a capable impedance analyzer. Pins 9, 10, and 11 on the IC are DVDD, AVDD1, and AVDD2, respectively.

I understand that it is usually desirable to separate analog and digital power sources to mitigate issues stemming from noise but I don't understand [why the datasheet then recommends tying "all supply connections and running from a single supply between 2.7V and 5.5V."](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5933.pdf) Doesn't that defeat the purpose of separating the pins/supplies?

Comment: So that you can pay more attention to decoupling and noise filtering around AVDD.

Comment: On what page of the datasheet does it recommend tying "all supply connections and running from a single supply between 2.7V and 5.5V."? I did not find that.

Comment: It's on page 8 figure 3.

Answer (score 1):

Only the manufacturer can say for certain, but the parasitic RLC between the chip itself and the pins on the package may be significant here. Bond wires have a significant inductance, so perhaps they don't want the noisy digital currents flowing through the bond wire that supplies the analog voltage.

Answer (score 1):

A common reason is that it lets you independently bypass the two power domains before connecting them.  This greatly attenuates switching noise that would otherwise end up on the analog lines.

I would interpret that datasheet to mean that you need to be careful about noise on the analog input pins (always a good idea), but the device isn't generating large enough currents on the digital supply that you're likely to run into problems using a common rail.  I would probably also leave a pair of pads for bypassing the digital power pin as well in case I ran into problems with noise.  It doesn't say they're required but that gives you the option to further reduce noise from the digital lines if you run into problems.